# Setting the correct environment variable before calling cx_Oracle on Linux

Tags: python, linux, oracle, environment-variables, cx-oracle

**Some context**

The package `cx_Oracle`, used to access Oracle databases from Python, requires setting a environment variable before loading and using the package. On Windows, one needs to add the folder `instantclient_12_2` to the PATH, while on Linux, instead, the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set, pointing to `instantclient_12_2` folder, what you can accomplish running the following command in the shell (before running your python script):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= path/to/instantclient_12_2/folder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**The problem**

On Windows, if you add the `instantclient_12_2` folder to PATH from the python script, everything works as desired and you don't have to oblige the user to change the PATH manually:

```
# On Windows, it works like a charm
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + 'Z:\\path\\to\\instantclient_12_2\\folder' 
import cx_Oracle
tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("server", "port", "DSN")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "password", tns)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from ...")
```

Unfortunately, the same does not apply on Linux (I'm running on *Oracle Linux Server release 7.3*, which is *CentOS*). The equivalent script (i.e. setting from the python script the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable instead of adding to the PATH) does not work:

```
# On Linux, the following code does not work
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/path/to/instantclient_12_2/folder' 
import cx_Oracle
tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("server", "port", "DSN")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "password", tns)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from ...")
```

Is it possible to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux in such way `cx_Oracle` will be able to use its value to load and work properly? If it is possible, how can you achieve this?

**Related questions**

There is a myriad of questions o SOF treating how to set environment variables from Python, but to the best of my knowledge none specifically dealing with the problem of loading `cx_Oracle` without needing to mess with environment variables manually.

Some answers affirm that "*there is no way to change the environment variables from a child process*". But in this case, any code executed by `cx_Oracle` is being executed in the context created by the main python script (i.e. a parent process, not a child), then presumably `cx_Oracle` should be able to access environment variables created in this context (what actually happens in Windows).

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot set LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside the process. This variable is examined by the *startup* code, so once the application has started it is completely ignored! Note that this is different from Windows. The only possible way to do this is to re-execute the process after setting the environment variable (or execute a new process that runs your real code) -- but that isn't likely to be an acceptable answer in most cases!

Generally the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in your login script, or effectively set globally by adding a file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d and running ldconfig. If neither of those is acceptable, you can also create a simple shell script that sets the environment variable and then executes your Python script.

Hope that answers your questions!

Comment: The variable is examined by _startup_ code? Then why appending to PATH on Windows works? Isn't the mechanism the same? If you elaborate on the the reasons behind this behavior, I would be glad to mark your answer as the correct.

Comment: Btw, I ended up with a workaround similar to creating a "simple shell script that sets the environment variable", but instead I just created a new python script A (_start.py_) which prepares the environment and then calls the script B (_system.py_).

Comment: Windows process startup behavior is different from Linux process startup behavior, so no the process isn't the same!